# IVsProject3.OpenItemWithSpecific returns -2147024809 for Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-2022

I'm updating a Visual Studio extension to work with Visual Studio 2022. As part of the code, I have this call to [`IVsProject3.OpenItemWithSpecific`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsproject3.openitemwithspecific?view=visualstudiosdk-2019):

```
IVsProject3 project = hierarchy as IVsProject3;

hr = project.OpenItemWithSpecific(
    itemIdFindAndLock,
    editorFlags,
    ref editorGuid,
    physicalView,
    ref logicalViewGuid,
    docDataExisting,
    out IVsWindowFrame windowFrame);
```

which was working as expected with the previous versions of Visual Studio, opening a specific editor for an item. In Visual Studio 2022 though, this returns `-2147024809`, which is cited in various sources as "parameter is incorrect" or "invalid argument".

I am not sure what does this mean, as all of the arguments have the same values as in Visual Studio 2019, except for the `docDataExisting`, which is obtained using `GetIUnknownForObject` and the difference seems normal for each debugging session:

```
IntPtr docDataExisting = Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject(this);
```

I am not sure how to debug this further as well.

Comment: Since VS 2022 has not been released, currently, the version is Preview. There may be some changes and issues need to be fixed. Perhaps you can try to report this issue in [Microsoft Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=8&entry=problem) or waiting for the release version and try again.

Comment: Yes, this is what I just did: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/IVsProject3OpenItemWithSpecific-returns/1534463